# Refresh required to see page layout properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hi i have a strange issue where refresh has be pressed to see the webpage properly, when loading the page for the first time the page is unformatted with no css. I am guessing its due to the jquery library not being loaded, i have moved around script links, but i have had no luck any suggestions please.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/hideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.equalHeight.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/Chart.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you publish your site in a test server? maybe is a problem with your network or cache configuration on your browser.

Comment: i am currently uploading to server directly, i will check my cache on hosting server, i dont know what cache settings are on there. thanks it could be the problem. i hope :-)  i will try to publish to another server now too.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the problem is with any javascript loading then you should load you all js file after loading you all html you are working with in you js files. Besides, If a js file is dependent on another js file then the dependent js file should be loaded later.

Comment: thanks for the anwer, i tried loading  html first but had no luck, im going to remove each script link 1 by 1 see i can find the culprit.